# Github search that excludes your own PRs

Tags: github, filtering, pull-request

Is there a way to filter pull requests that are not your own.  If I want only pull requests I've authored I write `is:pr author:steaks` in my filter.  I'd like to be able to write something liek `is:pr authorisnot:steaks`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fount my own answer.  GitHub allows negation with a minus sign.

`is:pr -author:steaks`